# Recycling bitmaps

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am working on project which involves operations on bitmaps. Because I don't want to have OutofMemoryError I'm trying to recycle each of unused bitmap. Unfortunatelly I've recycled too much and have 'trying to use a recycled bitmap' error.

I am using:

```
 Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, x,y,w,h, matrix, false);
 Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, w, h,true);
```

Should I recycle bmp after this methods or it is recycled by them? Like:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, x,y,w,h, matrix, false);
bmp.recycle();
```

Can I just after imageView.setImageBitmap() recycle one which previously was used here? E.g.

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
myBitmap.recycle();
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Consider using the BitmapFactory.Options when creating the Bitmap. Specifically look at inPurgeable... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

Comment: Is "trying to use a recycled bitmap" the exact and only error that you see regarding recycled bitmap? If it is, it might be worthwhile to try analyzing your stack trace and see if you can detect a pattern when the error happened (there is a central place in the framework where this exception is thrown although there is quite a few ways your code can get there).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should only recycle a bitmap when you do not need it anymore. However, you **do** need a bitmap when you want to *display* it. If you don't want to display it, then you can recycle a bitmap.

Comment: So this is good practice: myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap); newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap,x,y,w,h, matrix, false);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
myBitmap.recycle();?

Comment: No, it won't work and give you an exception because your bitmap is then recycled before it could be rendered. Calling setImageBitmap does not immediately render a bitmap to the screen. This happens at some future point during the next UI update cycle. And even then you need to keep your bitmap, because you assigned it to your ImageView. As soon as you don't use your ImageView anymore or as soon as you set a different bitmap, you can recycle the old bitmap. A safe place to recycle all old bitmaps is in Activity.onStop(). You could also use onPause but then you have to re-create them in onResume

Comment: but in my example there are two bitmaps: myBitmap (original) and newBitmap. I would like to recycle myBitmap as soon as possible after creating newBitmap and seting it to imageView.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I'm sorry. I should take a break for today :-) ... You are right, your example is good practice.

Comment: Don't worry :) I have one more question. You said that: "Calling setImageBitmap does not immediately render a bitmap to the screen. This happens at some future point during the next UI update cycle." So regarding my example I can still use recycle() just after setImageBitmap(newBitmap)?

Comment: Yes, it is safe to recycle the old bitmap immediately, since your ImageView does not use it anymore when you set newBitmap.

Comment: Ok, now I know everything and my project is working. Thank you for help!

Comment: @NobuGames That helped me a lot, thanks. I have a small question I am a beginner in Android and I was wondering we are recycling the old bitmap to save memory but we are creating a new one instead, I do not understand why is benefit ? How are we saving memory ?

Comment: @Lily That depends on what your app is doing. Imagine you create an image browser / gallery app where you can swipe the screen to browse from page A to the next page B with another image. When page B is open the image of page A would be recycled to save memory. It is impractical to load all images at once into RAM, you need to make sure that you only load bitmaps that are visible (or about to be visible) at a time in order to avoid an "out of memory" situation.

Comment: @NobuGames ok that makes sense, I have a question. if my application is drawing a bar depending on a value that it sent from a computer, each second this information is updates and the drawing is updated by calling the drawing class. In my drawing class I have two bitmaps the one Im assigning to canvas and I'm reusing it to draw the new draw and the other one is the one I'm assigning to ImageView and  I'm recycling this onStop. I'm getting out of memory error and when I looked to the log there is a lot of GC (around 1 each half a second). What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Lily It's hard to tell, but my guess is that your communication code with the computer may be the cause of the constant garbage collection and not your drawing routines. Drawing bitmaps does not trigger garbage collection. How does your app communicate with your computer?

Answer (score 1):

You only recycle bitmaps once you are done with them and are sure you never need to use the data in them again. It's not a magic method that you can use anywhere you like to give you more memory when dealing with bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to scale bitmap then I use the same reference:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, x,y,w,h, matrix, false);
```

When the first bitmap object loses its reference "bmp" it gets removed by GC (garbage collector) so you don't need to recyle anything. As for the image view it only references its source to "newBitmap" it does not create its own.