# Android Out of memory loading bitmaps

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have an android game that loads 6 images totaling 300kb. I've already read and implemented this article http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html and while it helped a little bit, it didn't solve my issue 100%.

When the game loads the first time it runs just fine. No errors or anything. Then when you close out of the game or press the home screen button and go back into the game later on it then presents the out of memory error, but only sometimes. In my on resume I'm only starting the game thread back up. I'm not loading in any images or anything like that. Surely I can't have the only game that loads 6 or more images?

My onResume

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        try{
            game.setIsPaused(false);
            game.startSounds();
            game.threadStart();
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Loading my images in its own thread

```
bg = bt.resizeBitmapPercent(bt.createBitmap(R.drawable.bg, context, options), imgPercentWidth, imgPercentHeight);
overlay = bt.resizeBitmapPercent(bt.createBitmap(R.drawable.overlay, context, options), imgPercentWidth, imgPercentHeight);
reel = bt.resizeBitmapPercent(bt.createBitmap(R.drawable.reels, context, options), imgPercentWidth, imgPercentHeight);
payOutBG = bt.resizeBitmapPercent(bt.createBitmap(R.drawable.payout, context, options), imgPercentWidth, imgPercentHeight);
achievement = bt.resizeBitmapPercent(bt.createBitmap(R.drawable.achievement, context, options), imgPercentWidth, imgPercentHeight);
```

Methods to resize  and create the bitmaps

```
public Bitmap createBitmap(int id, Context context, BitmapFactory.Options options){
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id, options);
}
public Bitmap resizeBitmapPercent(Bitmap bitmap, float w, float h){       
    float newWidth = bitmap.getWidth()*w;
    float newHeight = bitmap.getHeight()*h;
    float scaleWidth = (float) newWidth / bitmap.getWidth();
    float scaleHeight = (float) newHeight / bitmap.getHeight();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418354/recycling-bitmaps. Recycling bitmaps may solve your problem. Check the link.

Answer (score 0):

after closing the game always try to empty the bitmap

I usually use this code

```
bmp.recycle();
bmp = null;
System.runFinalization();
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
System.gc();
```

it'll recycle the bitmap and using garbage collector

Comment: When the game is closed or when it's paused? I'm recycling the images on game close but I read that you shouldn't recycle the images on pause is that true?

Comment: yes,after the game is closed. if you want to use it again,don't recycle it,recycle it when you done using it

Comment: I went ahead and added this, but I don't think it will fix my problem. My problem is caused when a user hits the home button and places the app in the background. Then they click on the icon and the game comes back to the front. I then get an out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by converting all my non transparent images from png to jpeg and lowering their quality to 60 in photoshop. It dropped my total image size from 300kb to 100ish kb. I was worried that the quality drop would look bad, but you couldn't tell there was any decrease in quality on either a smart phone or tablet.